# How to use 'value' of input tag in mithril.js

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I want to be able to store the value of the text inputted in a variable. I thought something like would work:

```js
m('input', {
    placeholder: 'Type to search...',
    oninput: () => { alert(this.value) }
})
```

I used `alert()` just to test it. Whenever an input was given it just gave a message "undefined".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow functions `() => {}` don't have a `this`. In order to rely on event handlers binding `this` to the element firing the event, you'd have to use:

```js
// the traditional function form...
m('input', {
    placeholder: 'Type to search...',
    oninput: function(){ alert(this.value) }
})

// ...or the modern method shorthand:
m('input', {
    placeholder: 'Type to search...',
    oninput(){ alert(this.value) }
})
```

Alternatively you can avoid `this` altogether (it is ambiguous after all, as we've just seen), keep the arrow function, and use the event object supplied as the first argument to the event handler:

```js
m('input', {
    placeholder: 'Type to search...',
    oninput: e => { alert(e.target.value) }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

All right.. I figured it out. I made a separate function and found the element using DOM and got the value from there:

```js
function boxValue() {
  alert(document.getElementById('searchBox').value);
}
```

```js
m('input', {
    id: 'searchBox',
    placeholder: 'Type to search...',
    oninput: () => { boxValue() }
})
```

I'll be marking this as the solution for now (as soon as I can), but if anyone comes up with a better answer, I will change the accepted answer.